# Prevent sap.m.popover from closing on click

Tags: sapui5

How do I prevent sap.m.popover from closing when the user clicks somewhere else on the page? Is there any solution to this requirement? I was not able to finde anything regarding this in the documentation.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isnt the property `modal` what you are looking for?

> The popover will not be closed when tapping outside the popover. It also blocks any interaction with the background. The default value is false.

Check the [demo kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com//#/api/sap.m.Popover) for the modal property. The Demo-kit is really something you should often use, it could help you a lot.

```
<Popover title="Test" class="sapUiContentPadding" placement="Bottom" modal="true">
    //whatever you want inside your popover
    <footer>
        <Toolbar>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button
                id="close"
                text="Close"
                press="handlClosePress" />
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
</Popover>
```